# cannot print webpage contents to a file in my local system using java

Tags: java

I cannot print contents of a webpage to a file in my local system.please help me to solve this problem

```
import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

public class bpart
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("my file location");


        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "my file location" ... really?

Comment: Unrelated: please look into java naming conventions. Class names go CamelCase ... and all names should express what they are about. An URL named oracle pointing to Google?

Comment: What Stultuske is saying "my file location" most likely isn't a valid file name in your OS.

Comment: You are not writing to a file, but `System.out`, which goes to the console.

Comment: Obviously "my file location" is a dummy. Just like "file/to/path" as an example

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a try-with-resources structure for you I/O and take a look a java-naming conventions. If you want to write the output of your http-call to a file you can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  URL googleUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
  try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(googleUrl.openStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("path/to/desired/file"))) {
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(inputLine);
      out.println(inputLine);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```